# how to use a loader from codepen in my code as a transition in between webpages

Tags: javascript, html, transition, loader, codepen

so what i want is to use this loader i found on codepen https://codepen.io/touneko/pen/ygOgWj as a transition in my webpages something like when i click on a button it loads this cat for 2 seconds and then show the other webpage that has the content

i have exported the zip file but i cant figure out how i can connect these

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="container">
      <video  class="background-video" autoplay loop muted plays-inline >
                <source src="images/ripple .mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video> 
      <div class="logo">
              <img class="logo2" src="images/grey.png ">
            <div class="divein-container">  <button id="diveInButton" class="divein"> <a href="/loadcat/pure-css-loading-cat/dist/index.html"> Dive In</button> </a> </div>
          </div> 
          
        </div>
      
        <script>
          document.getElementById('diveInButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            
              window.location.href = 'index.html';
              
         
              setTimeout(function() {
                  window.location.href = 'newpage.html'; 
              }, 2000);
          });
        </script>

      
  </body>
  </html>
```

so the home2 html is my main file the index file is the one containing this loader and the newpage is yk the page i want after it has finished loading

i have tried checking the paths and stuff and all of this is in the same folder